# Gradle: list of changed files as an input for task

Tags: gradle

This task successfully checks if it's up to date, but how can I get access to the changed files in the doLast block? The inputs directory includes a huge amount of files and inputs.files returns every file in that directory.

```
task foo {
  inputs.dir new File("path/to/files")
  doLast {
    // do stuff with changed files
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Gradle 1.0, this information is not yet exposed. A future version of Gradle will provide a public API for this.

Comment: Is this still the case? I'm on Gradle 1.4

Comment: Gradle 1.6 introduced a new, incubating API that gives access to such information. See the release notes.